# What is a good mic in the $200 range for miking an acoustic guitar (for use with Apogee duet portable studio)?

Tags: microphone, recording

I am considering purchasing an Apogee Duet (iPad/Mac version), to do a simple guitar/vocal setup. I already have an SM58 for vocals, but I need a mic for the guitar (steel string acoustic).

I have an M-Audio Nova condenser mic which I haven't used in years. I don't remember it being the greatest quality, but it could have been the M-Audio interface/preamps.

Is the Oktava MK-319 a good option if I can get a second-hand one off EBay for $200? Can anyone suggest a $200-$250 mic out-the-box?

Comment: shure-sm94 is a nice option
http://www.shure.com/americas/products/microphones/sm/sm94-instrument-microphone

Comment: But you're not intending to use the SM58 for _recording_ vocals, are you? I mean, it works and is completely ok for recording the singer in a rock band live, but if there's only an acoustic guitar as accompainment it's going to sound rather dull.

Comment: Well I was planning on it, but once you spend $600 on a duet, and $250 on an Oktava, you may as well stretch the budget a bit for a better vocal mic; what would you suggest? Maybe I could just use the Nova instead?

Comment: There are plenty of comparison recording sessions available on youtube. Just listen and decide which one suits you the most and go for it. After all it's YOUR ears and what YOU like.

Comment: As Eugene says, this site isn't for shopping recommendations - you'd be better off listening to one of the comparison sites for that sort of thing.

Comment: Further to Eugene's great suggestion, I strongly suggest http://tonefinder.com/ as this gives a nice summary and detail about the set up/recording technique.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the SM-57 or AKG C 1000 s.

I've used both in studio and live, for acoustic and electric guitars. The quality is down to the engineer (as always) but I've always had clear results with it. Out of the two, I much prefer the AKG but it is battery powered where as the Shure is not!

Although, if you can get a Sennheiser MD 421 II Large Diaphragm Dynamic Microphone second hand on Ebay, that is where I put my money!